# Что будет если не закрыть соединение curl_close()?

Tags: php, curl

Через ajax выполняю php-код, с помощью curl авторизуюсь и выполняю код. Таких ajax-запросов может быть очень много за день. Что может случиться, если я не буду использовать curl_close()?

Comment: Вроде ничего, с концом выполнения скрипта дескрипторы так же закрываются. Но кому надо чтобы в памяти на всё выполнения время висел мусор?

Comment: @Other Спасибо)

Comment: @Other, а соединение открытое переиспользовать не получится?

Comment: @Qwertiy, открытое будет соединять с тем, куда оно открыто. Если на дескриптору сделать новое назначение (`$curl = curl_init();`), то сборщик мусора упокоит старый канал. Вроде так.

Comment: @Other, но ведь можно и не сделать? Или нельзя?

Comment: @Qwertiy, что "не сделать"?

Comment: @Other, это: `$curl = curl_init();` - просто продолжать использовать старый.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я не спец в `PHP`, поэтому только предполагаю. Думаю что будет создан новый дескриптор, а старый уничтожат.

Comment: Продолжать использовать старый можно если в делаете 2 и более запросов за один прогон скрипта. Если по одному запросу то соединение будет закрыто как только отработает скрипт, переиспользовать его, в обычном php не выйдет.

Answer (score 1):

По завершении работы скрипта все ресурсы будут закрыты автоматически.

Если не вызвать `curl_close`, то соединение останется открытым и доступным для других `keep-alive` запросов из этого скрипта соответственно в пределах времени, сколько удалённая сторона готова ждать другие запросы. Поэтому если вы сделали запрос, получили ответ - и больше вам от удалённой машины ничего не нужно - лучше вызовите `curl_close`, чтобы не держать зря соединение.

А вот если вам к одной удалённой машине необходимы выполнить несколько запросов подряд - то вполне имеет смысл делать сначала один `curl_init` и затем переиспользовать этот дескриптор. Вызов `curl_close` явно запрещает переиспользовать соединение и будет создаваться новое соединение.

Т.е. код вида

```
$ch = curl_init();
foreach(...) {
    curl_setopt_array($ch, ...);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    ...
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Позволит сэкономить некоторое время, затрачиваемое на установку TCP соединения, а для HTTPS - и на согласование TLS, что ещё интереснее.

Релевантная заметка на [хабрахабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/184302/)